# Why bot.commands won't work in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code:

```
import discord 
import asyncio
from discord import Game
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print(bot.user.id)
print("botstart")
game = discord.Game("abc")
await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith("hi"):
    await message.channel.send("Hello")

    if message.content.startswith("ping"):
    await message.channel.send("Pong")

@bot.command
async def ping(ctx):
ctx.send("Pong!")

bot.run("(my token)", bot=True)
```

For some reason, `bot.event` works but `@bot.command(!ping)` part doesn't. I tried to fix it but i couldn't, even watching discord.py guides.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are overriding the on_message event, the bot no longer responds to any commands. To fix this add `await bot.process_commands(message)` to your on_message function for it to handle commands normally.

Source:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working